# Logging-in to beta sites doesn't work when not logged in to the Area 51

Tags: bug, beta-sites

At the first time I had massive problems logging-in to one of sites in beta stage (freelancing.stackexchange.com to be more specific, but it's the same for others, too) - the link (still) doesn't work (I need to log-in in order to log-in?), and automatic authentication when I'm logged to other sites doesn't work either - I have to be logged in Area 51 and just there in order to proceed with automatic auth, which is pretty annoying.

Is it a bug, or a feature request?

Comment: I'm currently in the beta for Math educators. I did log in successfully, and I'm still logged in on my tablet. But now I can't log in here, it asks for the confirmation email (which I deleted after loging in). I'm logged in to other SE sites. What gives?